# how to run php code in html and stored in sd card?

Tags: php

I am writing a code as channel.htm form and stored in sd memory card. But when I run the channel.htm page. It show me the php code. I do not know what should I do . can someone help ? 
I am doing experiment on arduino run on sd card.

HELP

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Arduino SD card Web Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1> Hello I am testing Arduino SD card connected to web page</h1>
            <p> A web page from SD card server. </p>

    <?php

    $a1=array( "channelOne"=>"-45",
    "channelTwo"=>"-100",
    "channelThree"=>"-20"  );

    $a2=array(
    "channelOne"=>"-48",
    "channelTwo"=>"-90",
    "channelThree"=>"-22"
    );

    $diff = array_map(
        function ($a1, $a2)
        {
            return abs($a1-$a2);
        }, $a1,$a2
    );
    print_r($diff);

    array_walk($a1,
    function ($v, $k) use ($a1,$a2)
    {
        $v = abs($a1[$k]-$a2[$k]);
    });
    print_r($a1);
    print_r($a2);

    ob_start();
    echo"<br>";echo"<br><pre>";print_r($diff);echo"</pre>";

    $content = ob_get_contents();

    $f = fopen("file.html", "w");
    fwrite($f, $content);
    fclose($f); 

    echo "<input type='submit' value='Write'>"



    ?> 

        </body>

    </html>
```

Here is the result
"-45", "channelTwo"=>"-100", "channelThree"=>"-20" ); $a2=array( "channelOne"=>"-48", "channelTwo"=>"-90", "channelThree"=>"-22" ); $diff = array_map( function ($a1, $a2) { return abs($a1-$a2); }, $a1,$a2 ); print_r($diff); array_walk($a1, function ($v, $k) use ($a1,$a2) { $v = abs($a1[$k]-$a2[$k]); }); print_r($a1); print_r($a2); ob_start(); echo"
";echo"

";print_r($diff);echo"

"; $content = ob_get_contents(); $f = fopen("file.html", "w"); fwrite($f, $content); fclose($f); echo "" /*$result=print_r($diff); $ourFileHandle = fopen("name.txt", 'w') ; fwrite($ourFileHandle,"diff"); fclose($ourFileHandle); echo "Written";*/ /*foreach($a1 as $Name=>$Temperature) { echo "Channel_Name"."
".$Name."
"."Actual_Temperature"."
".$Temperature."
"; } foreach($a2 as $Name=>$Temperature_Now) { echo "Channel_Name"."
".$Name."
"."Temperature_Now"."
".$Temperature_Now."
"; }*/ ?>

Comment: Read up on server-side vs client-side languages. Then start here http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php

Comment: So, is the PHP interpreter available for whatever your gadget is?

Comment: you need to read first client-server technology... PHP run in a server, html in the client

Comment: To explain why, .html extensions or any html variation is simply not php. The server, however you choose to load it, will not interpret it as php unless it is told to. If you're running it locally, you need to rename it to channel.php and run it somewhere that has php installed

Comment: PHP scripts can be run by double-clicking on them.  PHP scripts which *serve a web page* are another story.  If you just want to run the script itself, it needs to be opened by the PHP interpreter.  (Which probably doesn't handle `.htm` files by default.)  If you want to *serve a web page* then you need to use a web server.

Comment: Try taking advantage of the built in webserver in PHP 5.4+ http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 2):

You should copy your `channel.htm`(if its the only file you have) or the whole folder of pages that you got to the www folder of your wamp server and in case of xampp server its htdocs folder. Run the web services and goto `localhost/channel.htm` in first case or `localhost/<address to your page starting from www or htdocs folder>` in your web browser. This is the way you may run your web page containing php code. But do read some more on  server-side vs client-side languages and how php works at the back. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to ensure that you actually have php installed on your Arduino device.  I'm sure a quick Google around will find someone who has created various bits of software to do this.  Try searching for 'Arduino LAMP Server'.

Secondly, unless you've set it up very strangely, files that end in .html, or .htm will not parse PHP code.  The standard setup for all major web servers doesn't process a server-side language like PHP in HTML files, and mostly, PHP files end in '.php' (Some end in .php3, .php4, .php5 etc to indicate PHP version - but this is fairly rare actually).

It'll take some fiddling to get an arduino running a server and php process, but it may be doable, good luck.